# Mendelian dominant trait involved with Hypodontia

Tags: genetics

If the absence of teeth is a dominant trait, then why is it not seen in generations? My teacher taught that absence of teeth is a mendelian dominant trait, but why don't we see this trait if it is dominant?

Answer (score 1):

Hypodontia isn't a single gene phenotype, but a poli-genic mechanism involved with epistatic phenomenons and environmental scenarios.

The trasmission isn't clear till now, but when you're talking about a poli-gene phenotype isn't so easy to describe the way in which the trasmission is performed. You could find every info about this disease [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4336964/), in a meta-review study:

Comment: Note also that if there was indeed a dominant allele for hypodontia, then if the frequency of this allele is low enough, you would still not see it (or only very rarely).